# Two queries mysql in one json object and retrieve each details in Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter, object

I have two tables that I want to convert them to json like this:

```
$first_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `parameters` WHERE patient_id=7 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 10");
$second_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `pat_details` WHERE email='".$email."' AND phone_num='".$phone_num."'");
```

$first_query returns the 10 set of records which should be stored in an array and $second_query returns the objects.I need to merge Two queries mysql in one object json and retrieve the details of the result.

The output should be:

```
[
 {
  "firstname":"xyz",
  "id":"123456",
  "mail":"xyz@gmail.com",
  "parameters":[
     {
        "diabetic":"no",
        "hypertension":"yes",
     },
     {
        "diabetic":"no",
        "hypertension":"yes",
     },
     {
        "diabetic":"yes",
        "hypertension":"no",
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

I am not able to aggregate these two queries into one and encode the results in json

Comment: Please add your desired output as well as the code that you came up with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a join query or a sub query. Since the data is not relational to each other, there's not a huge performance benefit to this.

If you just want to combine the data, return or cast the data as an arrays, use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) on the two arrays, and then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

And be sure to make you queries safe from SQL injection. I'd suggest using the CodeIgniter Query Builder to make database interactions simpler and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution

```
$first_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `parameters` WHERE patient_id=7 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 10");
$json= $firstquery->result();
$second_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `pat_details` WHERE email='".$email."' AND phone_num='".$phone_num."'");

 $json2 = array();
 foreach($secondquery->result_array() as $row){
   $json2[] = array( 
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'address' => $row['address'],
    'mail' => $row['mail']
);
}
 $json['parameters'] = $json2;
 echo json_encode($json);
```